# Trying to parse out full name into two columns in SQL

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

I have a bit of a tricky situation.

The current name field I'm trying to parse out is in this form:

`Last, First MI`

For example:

```
Doe, John M 
Solis Olvera, Miguel P
Del Cid Donis, Emily D
```

I need to parse that out to last name and first name column and MI omitted.

How do I achieve this? I used the combination of charindex and substring but was unable to reach the desired resolution.

My Current logic is to get everything to the left of the comma for last name and to the right of the comma but before the first blank space for the first name. I'm not sure how to achieve the latter..

This is what I have tried so far:

```
select [patient name]
      ,left([patient name],charindex(',',[patient name])-1)
      ,substring([patient name],charindex(',',[patient name])+2,
        (CHARINDEX(' ',[patient name],CHARINDEX(' ',[patient name]) + 1)) - 
        (charindex(' ',[patient name])+1))  
    from Riskpool.dbo.RP_MasterFile a
```

I can't figure out the logic to get the blank space that comes after comma in each row..

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried so far...  And what version of SQL are you using

Comment: `code`
select [patient name]
      ,left([patient name],charindex(',',[patient name])-1)
      ,substring([patient name],charindex(',',[patient name])+2,(CHARINDEX(' ', [patient name],CHARINDEX(' ',[patient name]) + 1)) - (charindex(' ',[patient name])+1))
   ,CHARINDEX(' ', [patient name],CHARINDEX(' ',[patient name]) + 1)
   ,CHARINDEX(' ', [patient name],CHARINDEX(' ', [patient name],CHARINDEX(' ',[patient name]) + 1) + 1)   
 from Riskpool.dbo.RP_MasterFile a
`code`
I am using SSMS 2014.

Comment: Can you show an example of the output that you want?

Comment: @ThilinaNakkawita 

I just want the names to be in 2 columns. Last Name and First Name and no middle initial. so for example, Doe in last name, John in first name.

Del Cid Donis in Last name, Emily in first name.